# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'. [11]

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

My xml only works up to [version](http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo) `1.8` of the `spring-mongo.xsd` schema. When I try with the [latest](http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd) (Currently `3.0`) then I get these errors:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'. [11] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'mongo-ref' is not allowed to appear in element 'mongo:db-factory'. [12] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'username' is not allowed to appear in element 'mongo:db-factory'. [12] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'password' is not allowed to appear in element 'mongo:db-factory'. [12]
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="${mongo.replicaset}" write-concern="${mongo.write_concern:REPLICAS_SAFE}"/>
    <mongo:db-factory id="DbFactory" mongo-ref="mongo" dbname="${mongo.db}" username="${mongo.username}" password="${mongo.password}"/>
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="DbFactory"/>
        <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Based on other answers, I tried to use `credentials` attribute with a connection string but even that is getting rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix the xsd version to your matching `spring-data-mongo` version. (to prevent surprises and not "rely on the latest")
So:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="...
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.YOUR.VERSION.xsd">
```

---

To upgrade your xml to 3.0 (currently latest):
[See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3)

---

> ##### Table 4. Removed XML Namespace Elements and Attributes:
>
> | Element Attribute | Replacement in 3.x | Comment |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `<mongo:db-factory mongo-ref="…​" />` | `<mongo:db-factory mongo-client-ref="…​" />` | Referencing a com.mongodb.client.MongoClient. |
> | `<mongo:mongo-client credentials="…​" />` | `<mongo:mongo-client credential="…​" />` | Single authentication data instead of list. |
> | ... | ... | ... |

1. ```
   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'. [11]
   ```

   Use `mongo:mongo-client` (It changed from [1.8](https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.8.xsd) to [2.0](https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-2.0.xsd)).
2. ```
   cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'mongo-ref' is not allowed to appear in element 'mongo:db-factory'. [12]
   ```

   So, replace it with `mongo-client-ref` (referencing the client from 1.).
3. ```
   cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'username' is not allowed to appear in element 'mongo:db-factory'. [12] 
   cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'password' is not allowed to appear in element 'mongo:db-factory'. [12]
   ```

   You should use: `credential` attribute of `mongo-client`.

Please consider also Table 3 (*`writeConcern` now with different values*) as Table 5 (`mongo-client-ref`, `connection-string`).

For `connection-string`, best refer to [(current)Mongo DB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

---

Here is the edited xml after applying this answer, not sure if it's correct but I get no xml validation errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" replica-set="${mongo.replicaset}" />
    <mongo:db-factory id="DbFactory" mongo-client-ref="mongo" dbname="${mongo.db}" connection-string="mongodb://${mongo.username}:${mongo.password}@${mongo.db}" write-concern="${mongo.write_concern:REPLICAS_SAFE}" />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="DbFactory"/>
        <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Here is the link to the tables if anyone needs them. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb

Comment: regarding `REPLICAS_SAFE`: [javadoc](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#REPLICAS_SAFE): "Prefer `W2`"!